# Buck converter operating frequency range:

Tags: power, buck

I am looking for a buck converter IC for my project. In the data-sheet if the operating(or supporting) frequency range has not been mentioned, then how do we know about the range of frequencies it supports? For eg. in this data-sheet [LTC3637](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3637fa.pdf) there is no mention of operating frequency range and am not able to figure out the same.

Comment: What about pages 11 and 12 of the datasheet? Doesn't that tell you enough? It even has pretty graphs for those that can't read.

Answer (score 1):

Figure 3 in the data sheet shows what you need: -

[image]